# Detect use a private key by more than one or by someone other than the owner

Tags: cryptography, protocols, deletion

I'm designing a protocol over the SSL but I faced a challenge. In the network each user takes a private key from authority. I want to just the owner can use his/her the private key. there are two situations:

1. the owner gives his/her private key to another or
2. the owners device will compromise and the hacker steals his/her private key.

I want to prevent or detect these. I read about traitor tracing but it seems impractical by now. has anyone an idea?
thank you.

Comment: This feels like an XY problem. Why do you need to ensure only the owner can access their private keys in ways that a simple 'warning, take good care of your private let material' message is not good enough?

Comment: This seems like a similar issue with passwords. Passwords are private and you don’t want them shared. I would suggest something like MFA and one time codes. If a user uses their private key, they must also input a one time code

Comment: @WouterVerhelst no. because this is a protocol and deploys in protocol stack. now wants to know if one send malicious traffic. it's not SSL, it just a protocol in protocol stack over ssl and does not care about real payload

Comment: @pm1391 right! but what if the user gives his/her private key to another?!!!!

Comment: If they give their key to another user, they would also have to have the one time pin/token for the other factor